# Buffering kafka messages with Flux

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream

I have kafka input and output topic.
What i do is i write in topic A and want to receive message in topic B but with buffering. 
My code looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> stringFlow() {
        return flux ->
            flux.window(4)
                .flatMap(m -> m);
    }
```

Input topic:

```
A
A
B
```

Output topic:

```
A
% Reached end of topic test-topic [0] at offset 78
A
% Reached end of topic test-topic [0] at offset 79
B
% Reached end of topic test-topic [0] at offset 80
```

I was expecting Flux to be kafka stream with messages and not each kafka message to be Flux.
Is there way to buffer kafka messages so i can store i.e. 10 messages remove duplicates and then publish them?

Answer (score 0):

`buffer()`, rather than `window()` is the operator you need if you just want the results returned as a collection rather than a `Flux`.

If you also want to filter duplicates from the resulting collection, you can use a `Set` rather than a `List` to store the values by passing a HashSet supplier as the second parameter:

`flux -> flux.buffer(10, HashSet::new)`